# How to split a string to two numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers, int, coordinates

I want to split an input into two different floats the input is `52.5033390,-0.1237830` (there will always be a comma `,` between the two numbers with no space)

```
while True:
    number = 0 #clears value
    number = input("Enter a lat and long") #e.g 52.5033390,-0.1237830
    number = number.split(",") #splits the input into two values
    lat = number[0] #52.5033390 float
    long = number[1] #-0.1237830 float
```

Comment: You'll need to parse the string values to actual floats: `lat = parseFloat(number[0]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split it in two different variables as `float`:

```
_lat, _long = map(float, number.split(","))
```